# Publish videostream from animated frames in c# application

Tags: c#, streaming, skiasharp

I have a c# program that renders frames on a canvas using SkiaSharp.
For this I use simple functions as `canvas.DrawRect()`.

But instead of drawing the result each frame on an image, I would like to publish a video stream, so I can subscribe on it using vlc media player or a webbrowser.

I've looked into ffmpeg but I can't get it working.

What is the best way to accomplish this streaming functionality?